# What is the purpose of the "START WITH" part of a SQL sequence?

Tags: sql, oracle

In oracle SQL, a sequence is dfined like so :

```
CREATE SEQUENCE sup_seq
    MINVALUE 1
    MAXVALUE 999
    START WITH 5
    INCREMENT BY 1
    CACHE 20;
```

What is the point of having the "START WITH" part ? If we have a minimum value , doesn't that imply that we start with that value? What is useful regarding `START WITH` ?

Comment: As the name says, Default starting number would be the minimum value you specifiy. Sometimes, when some old data(in table) already exists with say a max of 1000 .. we may need to start our sequence from 1001.. in tht case, `START WITH` will benefit us!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally, it would be pretty unusual to specify both `MINVALUE` and `START WITH` when defining a sequence and to have those values be different.  Personally, I don't think that I've ever explicitly specified a `MINVALUE` since I find `START WITH` to be more self-explanatory.

One case where two values would be useful would be a sequence that is set to cycle.  For example

```
CREATE SEQUENCE sup_seq
    MINVALUE 1
    MAXVALUE 999
    START WITH 5
    INCREMENT BY 1
    CACHE 20
    CYCLE;
```

would start with 5 (the `start with`), generate values through 999 (the `maxvalue`), and then restart at 1 (the `minvalue`).  That's not a particularly common use case but it's entirely possible.